# Is there a program that offers an instruction to assert on the oracle price of an asset?

Tags: transaction, oracles

I want to create a transaction that will succeed *only if* the price of a certain asset is greater than or equal to some value. Essentially, I want to add an instruction to the transaction that will fail the transaction if the price is out of bounds.

```
const tx = new Transaction()
  // Log a memo, on-chain.
  .add(new TransactionInstruction({
    data: new TextEncoder().encode('Hello world'),
    keys: [],
    programId: 'MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr',
  }))
  // Add an instruction that asserts on the price of an asset.
  .add(new TransactionInstruction({
    data: u64().encode(100000000n), /* minimum price */
    keys: [{pubkey: SOME_PRICE_ORACLE, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}],
    programId: SOME_MAGIC_PRICE_ASSERTION_PROGRAM,
  }));
```

Does there exist a program that offers an instruction to make such an assertion?

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't already a built in instruction of the [Pyth oracle program](https://docs.pyth.network/documentation/how-pyth-works/oracle-program).

Answer (score 4):

working on program that can do this!

https://github.com/Jac0xb/lighthouse

Lets you make assertions on account info, account data, etc!

Comment: Amazing! Update this answer with a code example when it's ready.